# flutter web "build.command" failed netlify deployment

Tags: node.js, flutter, netlify

I am getting a lot of error stating

> Error: The type "JSObject" can"t be used as supertype.

> Error: The method "hasProperty" isn"t defined for the class "EventTarget".

> Error: The method "hasProperty" isn"t defined for the class "EventTarget".

I am able to build locally on my machine using `flutter build web --release`, but for some reason netlify has issues I am not able to explain. I am using `flutter channel stable`.

I have updated my `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
name: jlg_technology
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' 
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.2 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.7.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.4.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.10
  firebase_auth: ^4.6.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.7.0
  flutter_markdown: ^0.6.13+1
  youtube_player_iframe: ^4.0.4
  flutter_stripe: ^9.4.0
  http: ^1.2.0
  provider: ^6.0.5
  flutter_form_builder: ^9.1.1
  intl: ^0.18.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.2
  mobile_scanner: ^4.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

and `package.json`

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@netlify/functions": "^2.5.1",
    "square": "^10.0.0"
  }
}
```

I assume the issue lies within my dependencies, but was not able to isolate the issue based on which package is breaking my build. I introduced netlify functions so I was thinking that the package.json would be the culprit even though there are few packages I use.

Comment: Is the error at build time?  If so you want to follow this guide to give us all of the most relevant details?  https://answers.netlify.com/t/support-guide-failed-build-debugging-advice-preparing-the-best-help-request/73269 . If instead it's at browse time, could you share a link to your site that shows the problem?